# How to prevent uploading restricted video on site?

Tags: video, upload

I want to prevent uploading of restricted video(like porn video ) on my site .

So is that possible to restrict user's to prevent uploading of this type of video ?

What would be the solution for this problem ?

Comment: Artificial intelligence? Or a YouTube like sized database and frame matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An auditor and an approval process. Yes, you need to watch the entire thing.

To be honest, if you're asking this, you don't want to do this. You're not ready for anything of volume at least.